# Undesirable Nest Loop vs. Hash Join in PostgreSQL 9.6

Tags: postgresql, performance, join, postgresql-9.6, row-level-security, query-performance

I've a trouble with PostgreSQL 9.6 query planning. My query looks like this:

```
SET role plain_user;

SELECT properties.*
FROM properties
JOIN entries_properties
  ON properties.id = entries_properties.property_id
JOIN structures
  ON structures.id = entries_properties.entry_id 
WHERE structures."STRUKTURBERICHT" != ''
  AND properties."COMPOSITION" LIKE 'Mo%'
  AND (
    properties."NAME" LIKE '%VASP-ase-preopt%'
    OR properties."CALCULATOR_ID" IN (7,22,25)
  )
AND properties."TYPE_ID" IN (6)
```

I have Row-Level Security enabled for the above-used tables.

- with `set enable_nestloop = True`, the query planner runs
  Nested Loop joining with a total running time of about 37 seconds: https://explain.depesz.com/s/59BR
- with `set enable_nestloop = False`, the Hash Join method is used and the query time is about 0.3 sec:  https://explain.depesz.com/s/PG8E

I did `VACUUM ANALYZE` before running the queries, but it didn't help.

I know that it is not a good practice to `set enable_nestloop = False`, and any other similar options for the planner. But how could I "convince" the planner to use hash joins without disabling nested loops?

Rewriting the query is an option.

If I run the same query under a role that bypasses RLS, then it is executed very fast. The row-level security policy looks like this:

```
CREATE POLICY properties_select
ON properties
FOR SELECT
USING (
  (
    properties.ouid = get_current_user_id()
    AND properties.ur
  )
  OR (
    properties.ogid in (select get_current_groups_id())
    AND properties.gr
  )
  OR properties.ar
);
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a bit confused: why have `AND properties."TYPE_ID" IN (6);` and not `= 6;`?

Comment: @Vérace while = is more widly used, they both get planed the same way. My assumption is that he's playing with more than one value, or an ORM is being a tad lazy.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What's happening here is the Nested Loop is way off on one side. Nested Loops work *really* well when one side is very small, such as returning one row. In your query, the planner fumbles here and estimates that a Hash Join will return just one row. Instead, that Hash Join (property_id = id) returns 1,338 rows. This forces 1,338 loops to run on the other side of the Nested Loop which already has 3,444 rows. That's a hella-lot when you're only expecting one (which isn't even much of a "loop"). Anywayy..

Further examination as we move down shows that the Hash Join is really borked by the estimations arising from this,

```
Filter: (((properties."COMPOSITION")::text ~~ 'Mo%'::text) AND (((properties."NAME")::text ~~ '%VASP-ase-preopt%'::text) OR (properties."CALCULATOR_ID" = ANY ('{7,22,25}'::integer[]))))
```

PostgreSQL expects that to return one row. But it doesn't. And, that's really your problem. So some options here, that don't involve taking out a sledge hammer and disabling `nested_loop`

- You can add an index or two to `properties` to help it potentially skip the seq scan entirely, or better estimate the return.

  ```
  CREATE INDEX ON properties USING ( "TYPE_ID", "CALCULATOR_ID" );
  -- the gist_trgm_ops may or may not be needed depending on selectivity of above.
  CREATE INDEX ON properties USING GIST (
    "COMPOSITION" gist_trgm_ops,
    "NAME"        gist_trgm_ops
  );
  ANALYZE properties;
  ```
- Alternatively, you can move the properties stuff to a CTE or subselect with `OFFSET 0` which creates a fence.

  ```
  WITH t AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM properties.
    WHERE "COMPOSITION" LIKE 'Mo%'
    AND (
      "NAME" LIKE '%VASP-ase-preopt%'
      OR "CALCULATOR_ID" IN (7,22,25)
    )
    AND "TYPE_ID" IN (6)
  )
  SELECT * FROM structures
  JOIN t ON (
    structures.id = entries_properties.entry_id
  )
  ```